# JSON body to List<int>, List<decimal> and long

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, http, post

I have a C# Website and Web API combined with a Save-method in one of my API Controllers. This method only allows HttpPosts. What I want to send in the body is a `List<int>`, `List<decimal>` and `long`.

Since HttpPost methods in API Controllers only allow one parameter to work, I tried both a `JObject` and `string` as parameter. When I use string it's always null, when I use JObject it's not null but incorrectly copied from the body. Because these are null and incorrectly copied, the converting to the `List<int>`, `List<decimal>` and `long` are also not working.

---

Parameter as string:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ActionName("save")]
public bool SaveOrders([FromBody] string jsonData)
{
    // Convert jsonData string to List<int>, List<decimal>, long
    JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
    List<int> productIds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json["productIds"].ToString(), typeof(List<int>));
    List<decimal> prices = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json["prices"].ToString(), typeof(List<decimal>));
    long dateInTicks = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json["dateInTicks"].ToString(), typeof(long));

    ...
}
```

with POST-body:

```
"{
    "productIds": "[20, 25]",
    "prices": "[0.40, 7.40]",
    "dateInTicks": "1402444800"
}"
```

When I debug this above, the parameter-string is always null.

---

Parameter as JObject:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ActionName("save")]
public bool SaveOrders([FromBody] JObject jsonData)
{
    // Convert jsonData JObject to List<int>, List<decimal>, long
    dynamic json = jsonData;
    string sProductIds = (string)json["productIds"];
    string sPrices = (string)json["prices"];
    string sDateInTicks = (string)json["dateInTicks"];
    List<int> productIds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sProductIds, typeof(List<int>));
    List<decimal> prices = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sPrices, typeof(List<decimal>));
    long dateInTicks = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sDateInTicks, typeof(long));

    ...
}
```

with POST-body:

```
productIds: "[20, 25]",
prices: "[0.40, 7.40]",
dateInTicks: "1402444800"
```

When I debug this, the parameter-JObject is:

```
{
  "productIds: \"": {
    "20, 25]\",\nprices: \"": {
      "0.40, 7.40]\",\ndateInTicks: \"1402444800\"": ""
    }
  }
}
```

and the sProductIds, sPrices and sDateInTicks are null.

---

I know I'm doing some things wrong, therefore this question, since I don't how I should change it.

---

Edit 1 (Rafal's suggestion):

In my config file I added one line:

```
// Only allow JSON response format
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
// Added the following line:
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

And my method is changed:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ActionName("save")]
public bool SaveOrders([FromBody] Data jsonData)
{
    if (jsonData != null)
    {
        if (jsonData.productIds != null && jsonData.prices != null)
        {
            return SavePrices(jsonData.productIds, jsonData.prices, jsonData.dateInTicks);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("One of the objects is null, so we can't continue.");
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The send data is null, so we can't continue.");
        return false;
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public List<int> productIds { get; set; }
    public List<decimal> prices { get; set; }
    public long dateInTicks { get; set; }
}
```

But although the Data-parameter isn't null, both the Lists inside of it are and the long is 0 as well.

---

Edit 2:

With the FireFox' RESTClient Body:

```
"productIds":[20,25],"prices":[0.4,7.4],"dateInTicks":1402444800
```

Why is the JObject parameter this:

```
{
  "\"productIds\":": {
    "20,25],\"prices\":": {
      "0.4,7.4],\"dateInTicks\":1402444800": ""
    }
  }
}
```

instead of this:

```
{
  \"productIds\":[20,25],\"prices\":[0.4,7.4],\"dateInTicks\":1402444800
}
```

It automatically removes the first `[` with the arrays and replaces it with `:" {"`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class:

```
public class Data
{
    public List<int> productIds { get; set; }
    public List<decimal> prices { get; set; }
    public long dateToTicks { get; set; }
}
```

And change the signature of you API method to receive it as parameter.

Note that properties names are pascal case. I did that on purpose as default configuration of deserializer will not allow camel case. To handle your json and use 'normal' properties casing add:

```
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver 
= new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

line in your site configuration file you will find it in `App_Start` folder for newer template or directly in `Global.asax.cs`. 
The config is of type `HttpConfiguration`.

---

Further investigation leads me to conclusion that you have invalid (well not invalid as far as json validator is concerned but not appropriate to the task at hand) json content. If you post it as:

```
{
   "productIds": [20, 25],
   "prices": [0.40, 7.40],
   "dateToTicks": "1402444800"
}
```

**without** any additional quotes then it will deserialize to Data class. If you need to retain it as is then you would need to deserialize is by hand as if you loose wraping quote then you have json object with 3 string properties not lists of values.

Comment: I tried what you said, and although the Data-parameter itself isn't null, the `List<int>`, `List<decimal>` both are and the `long` is also 0.

Comment: I've added the "Edit 1" in the main post for a bit more details.

Comment: Is your json exactly as you posted it? I men the quotes as if it is it is invalid.

Comment: Yes, and I even tried multiple syntaxes: with brackets or without, with double quotes or without... `"{ "productIds": "[20, 25]", ... }"`; `{ "productIds": "[20, 25]", ...}`; `"productIds": "[20, 25]", ...`; `productIds: "[20, 25]", ...` All the same results

Comment: Try without them as I posted.

Comment: The easiest way to generate json i javascript is to create an object that contains what you need with arrays and ints and then call `JSON.stringify(yourObjectVariable)` it will be valid and nice.

Comment: The json you've posted still gives the same result. And my json will later on be send by an Android App, but right now I'm only testing the method in FireFox' RESTClient Plug-in. But I will make a quick JavaScript fiddle / mini-project to convert some test-data with `JSON.stringify` as you suggested.

Comment: The result of the fiddle `var Data = { 
    productIds: [20, 25], 
    prices: [0.40, 7.40], 
    dateInTicks: 1402444800 
};
 
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(Data); 
 
alert(jsonString);` is `{"productIds":[20,25],"prices":[0.4,7.4],"dateInTicks":1402444800}`. But this still gives null, null and 0..

Comment: The problem of my Edit 2 is solved by using `application/json` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in my `Content-Type` HttpPOST-header.